# how to use variable on FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba

i don't know how to use **Varibale** (For example **X** ).

With this code im looking for ***PS16111*** which is a PO number, I create a new Column, then every rows has the same value will be #N/A, then at the end of this code I will delete those **#N/A** lines which means that all ***PS16111*** will be deleted. this is what I want to do but with different Inputs.

I tried different way to use a variable instead of ***PS16111*** but i couldn't find any way.

Thanks.

Columns(3).EntireColumn.Insert

With Range("C2:C" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

```
        .FormulaR1C1 = =IF(RC[1]="""","""",IF(RC[1]=""PS16111"",NA()))"

        .Value = .Value

        On Error Resume Next

        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete

End With

On Error GoTo 0

Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
```

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you want to do, but to use a variable in FormulaR1C1 you may just concatenate it on the string: `"IF(RC[1]=" & X & ",NA())"`

Comment: I want to repace PS16111 with a variable X, but i don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are missing a leading `"` in your formula

Then to answer your question, use

```
x = "PS16111"
rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[1]="""","""",IF(RC[1]=""" & x & """,NA()))"
```

will result in the formula

```
=IF(B1="","",IF(B1="PS16111",NA()))
```

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

'Before everything Thanks to **chris neilsen** to complete the puzzle.
I put all codes together in this case you want to use this in your project.

With this code you will be able to find a String located in **C2 in Sheet2**.

Then back to **Sheet1** and create a new empty **Column C**

Then count how many lines are in the Sheet1

Then looking for Variable **X** and if it found it will be **#N/A** , if not **False**.

All rows contain #N/A value will be deleted.

At the end Column C will be delete.

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Dim X As String

X= Worksheets("sheet2").Range("C2").Value

Worksheets("sheet1").Select

Columns(3).EntireColumn.Insert

With Range("C2:C" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

```
         .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[1]="""","""",IF(RC[1]=""" & X & """,NA()))"

        .Value = .Value

        On Error Resume Next

        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete

End With

On Error GoTo 0

Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
```